# Issue in oozie installation: Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.UnknownHostException: master

Tags: oozie

I tried to install `oozie` on my pc and looks like successfully installed

```
oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status
System mode: NORMAL
```

But when running an `oozie` job it is showing below error

Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.UnknownHostException: master

*Can you please suggest what could be the reason?*

Comment: Welcome @sumeet agrawal, for your next ost I suggest you to have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. :)

Comment: This issue will be solved by setting IP instead of hostname at 'job.properties' file change the namenode and jobtracker.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this failure could be further examined in oozie.log, which usually located in /var/log/oozie folder for CDH distribution. Or the log location could be examined with command:

```
ps -ef | grep oozie
```

and look for "-Doozie.log.dir=..."

And the oozie host needs to be reachable from the host where the command line is invoked. Try telnet to oozie port to make sure connection is good. An example session is like this:

```
  [cloudera@localhost hadoop-yarn]$ telnet master 11000
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to master.
  Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: I am running throgh the below command:

sumeet@hadoopmaster:~$ oozie job -oozie http://master:11000/oozie -config /usr/local/oozie-3.3.2-cdh4.7.0/src/examples/target/oozie-examples-3.3.2-cdh4.7.0-examples/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.UnknownHostException: master

Comment: In that case, you could replace http://master with http://localhost and try again. Basically, the oozie host needs to be reachable from the host where the command line is invoked.